# hadoop sequence file collection

Tags: hadoop, sequencefile

How can a reducer (with a Text key and an Iterable MapWritable value) output all its Map's to a sequence file so as to preserve grouping on its key?  For example, suppose the mappers send records to reducers that look like:

```
<"dog", {<"name", "Fido">, <"pure bred?", "false">, <"type", "mutt">}>
<"cat", {<"name", "Felix">, <"color", "black">, <"origin", "film">, <"date", "1919">}>
<"dog", {<"name", "Lassie">, <"type", "collie">, <"origin", " short story">}>
```

I'd like the sequence file to be written as:

```
key = "dog"
value =  {
            {<"name", "Fido">, <"pure bred?", "false">, <"type", "mutt">},
            {<"name", "Lassie">, <"type", "collie">, <"origin", "short story">}
         }

key = "cat"
value = {
            {<"name", "Felix">, <"color", "black">, <"origin", "film">, <"date", "1919">}
        }
```

I'm guessing that I need to create a custom value output class that implements Writable, but I'm not sure how to do this since Collections don't really work with sequence files as far as I can tell.  I'd like to do this so that the next map/reduce stage will read in all Maps associated with each key as a unit.

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

As you note, you could create a custom Writable that extends [ArrayWritable](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/ArrayWritable.html):

```
public class MapWritableArray extends ArrayWritable {
    public MapWritableArray() {
        super(MapWritable.class);
    }
}
```

Then in your reducer you'll need to accumulate the iterable of MapWritable values into an array (remembering to copy the values as the underlying contents change with each iteration). Something like (completely untested, not compile verified and not optimized):

```
MapWritableArray mapWritableArray = new MapWritableArray();
ArrayList<MapWritable> valList = new ArrayList<MapWritable>();
for (MapWritable value : values) {
    MapWritable copy = ReflectionUtils.newInstance(context.getConfiguration(), MapWritable.class);
    ReflectionUtils.copy(context.getConfiguration, value, copy);
    valList.add(copy);
}
mapWritableArray.set(valList.toArray(new MapWritable[0]));
```